# Button event that calls method does not affect public int

Tags: c#, buttonclick, method-call

This is my first question here and, although it's probably a very nooby one, it's had me stumped for quite a while. I'm using a simplified example to explain.

On a Console Application, I have a public int 'x' set to 0 and a method 'test' which changes it to 1. When 'test' is called in Main, the value of X is now 1 (as expected).

```
    public int x = 0;

    public void test()
    {
        x = 1;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.test();
        Console.WriteLine(program.x);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

However (and this is what I don't understand), when using a button_Click event to call the same 'test' method on a Windows Form Application, 'x' remains as 0:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int x = 0;

    public void test()
    {
        x = 1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.test();
        MessageBox.Show("" + x);
    }
}
```

So to summarize, what I am wanting to happen is for 'test' to be called when the button is clicked, changeing the value of 'x' to 1. Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You've create two separate instances of `Form1`. Calling the `test()` method on the second instance is not going to affect the value of `x` in the first instance.

Change the button click event, so that you're not creating a new `Form1`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test();  // now it'll call test() on the current instance, and modify x as you expect

    MessageBox.Show("" + x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That was the last piece of the puzzle. My program final works!

Answer (score 0):

Because is happening for the form that you created with `Form1 form = new Form1();`

Remove that line,call only `test()` and try again, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!